# How to pass more than one element of a list to argument in a custom function - Python

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I created a function, that is a wrapper for a statistical regression function of the statsmodels package.
I can pass one dependent variable and one independent variable to the argument parameters without error. The problem comes when I attempt to pass multiple columns (independent variables) i.e. exog =['indvar1','indvar2']
I have tried converting the data frame columns to a list

```
pred = df.columns.tolist()
pred = df.columns.values.tolist()
```

But I still get the same error.

```
The error is : KeyError: "None of [Index([('TARP', 'Lehman', 'Recovery_Act', 'T10Y2Y', 'DFF')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

This function:

```
Bob1 = sect_arma1.cv(model_data,endog ='Technology',exog = pred)
```

fails in ternally at this line according to the error description.:

```
280 --> exog = X[[exog]][1:Train_size]
```

Note, the endog argument does not fail because one quoted variable works e.g. 'Technology'

Comment: Think of a way so that people can replicate your problem and then give solution on it. Present some example data. Then a minimal amount of code to do something using statsmodel (since you mentioned it) and then show the error.

Comment: My favorite stackoverflow page since recently: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Highly recommended!

Comment: Don’t use `.values`. We don’t have the rest of your code (you should probably rectify that), but my guess is that it is very unidiomatic. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use whichever method, described below is appropriate to your needs. For all the examples below I will use the dummy data made at the end of this solution.

> #### Get a list of column names:
>
> You can get a list of column names by `df.columns.tolist()`.

```py
df.columns.tolist()
```

**Output**:

```
['x', 'y']
```

> #### Get the data as numpy array:
>
> You can get the data a numpy array as follows.

```py
df.to_numpy()
```

**Output**:

```
array([[ 18, 120],
       [ 20, 110],
       [ 22, 120],
       [ 25, 135]])
```

> #### Get the data of a column as list:
>
> You can get the data of a certain column as a list as follows.

```py
df['x'].tolist()
```

**Output**:

```
[18, 20, 22, 25]
```

---

#### Dummy Data

Let's make some dummy data first to explain a few things.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [18,20,22,25], 'y': [120,110,120,135]})
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
    x    y
0  18  120
1  20  110
2  22  120
3  25  135
```